# Enforcing Non-Negative Difference between Window Value and Filter Value in Customized Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have this customized neural network where I introduced a variation inspired by convolutional neural networks (CNNs). Instead of the conventional element-wise multiplication, I have implemented element-wise subtraction, drawing from ideas discussed in a specific [research paper](https://github.com/huawei-noah/AdderNet). However, I believe that for the purpose of my question, familiarity with the specific network details might not be necessary.

We have that in convolutional neural networks, each element in the window (xii) is multiplied by its corresponding filter value (fjj). While in my customized neural network, we perform element-wise subtraction instead of multiplication.

My question is, is there any way to guarantee that the difference between the window value (xii) and its corresponding filter value (fjj) is non-negative? In simpler terms, is there a best practice to enforce the constraint xii - fjj >= 0?